# How to control canvas if it got label, the outside label will be hidden

Tags: canvas, label

I using two open source chart package for my project.

1. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/
2. https://piechart-outlabels.netlify.com/

I encounter that the outside label will be hidden if over the canvas dimension.

How do i scale small the canvas but the dimension remain same?

i read the docs chart.js it look like cannot control by them. Some of my code will be shown in below.

```
  new Chart(this.ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        borderColor: bgColor
    }],
    labels: ['', '', ''],
  },
  options:{
    zoomOutPercentage: 20,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    plugins: {
      labels: [{
        render: 'value',
        position: 'outside',
      }],
      outlabels: {
        backgroundColor: "#8C1DFF", // Background color of Label
        borderColor: "#001BFF", // Border color of Label
        borderRadius: 17, // Border radius of Label
        borderWidth: 10, // Thickness of border
        color: 'white', // Font color
        display: true,
        lineWidth: 10, // Thickness of line between chart arc and Label
        padding: 10,
        stretch: 100, // The length between chart arc and Label
        text: "%l (%p)",
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: ca]

Answer (score 0):

you just miss layout: {
padding: 135
}

```js
var chartss = new Chart('chart-1', {
  "type" : "pie",
  "data" : {`enter code here`
    "labels" : [ "Female", "Male", "Other" ],
    "datasets" : [ {
      "data" : [ 1819000, 1659900, 1344 ],
      "backgroundColor" : [ "rgba(139,0,0,1.000)", "rgba(0,0,205,1.000)", "rgba(0,128,0,1.000)" ]
    } ]
  },
  "options" : {
    "responsive" : true,
    "title" : {
      "display" : true,
      "position" : "bottom",
      "text" : "GENDER WISE CHART"
    },
    "legend" : {
      "position" : "bottom"
    },
    "maintainAspectRatio" : true,
            plugins: {
                    legend: false,
                    outlabels: {
                    text: '%l %v',
                    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.000)',
                    stretch: 30,
                    font: {
                        resizable: true,
                        minSize: 12,
                        maxSize: 18
                    }
                }
                },
                layout: {
                 padding: 135
               }
  }
});
```